# Editing using Pop-up modal

Tags: javascript

I've some problems with my Edit function for editing my groups table. the fields are `"group_id(primary key), cat_id(foreign key), group_name"`
I used the group_id as the identifier of which group information I should edit

This is my Edit button

```
a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" class="btnedit">Edit</a
```

When i clink the Edit Button, this modal will pop up

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"></div>
```

I added an hidden input type to hold the group_id

" id="editID">

I used this javascript to get the group_id value.

```
<script>

  $('.btnedit').click(function(){

    var url = '<?php echo DEFAULT_URL."group/edit_group/";?>';

    $.post(url,{'group_id':$('#editID').val()},function(res){

    if(res)

      {

      }

    });

  });

</script>
```

My question now is how will I apply the vallue that I got from my javascript into the modal to edit the details from the group_id that I seected?

Comment: Do you want to add the response to the modal as html?  If yes, is there anything else you want to do besides adding HTML?

Comment: I wanted to use html to make things easier but my team mates wanted to use the modal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

  $('.btnedit').click(function(){

    var url = '<?php echo DEFAULT_URL."group/edit_group/";?>';

    $.post(url,{'group_id':$('#editID').val()},function(res){

    if(res)

      {
         $('#myModal2').html('<div><p>'+res.value+'</p></div>');
      }

    });

  });

</script>
```

???